# formatting <input type="time"> to 12 hour format with no seconds/milliseconds

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to format some times for display.

```
  <input ng-change="changeTimeBehaviours()" ng-model="booking.time" type="time" >
```

How can I add formatting to this to be h:mma format ? (eg 2:30PM)

I used

```
var _time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language,{hour:'2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
```

and it did the job but i cant use that with the type='time' because it expects a date time object not a string.

I'm using

```
{{booking.time | date:"h:mma"}}
```

in a template in another section and it works perfectly.

~Edit

I was using ionic serve to test the app, and it was giving me this as the time

11:59:18.046 PM

when I closed the quit the serve and refreshed the page, chrome had the time flag exactly how I wanted it to be,

11:59 PM

so I've come to the conclusion that its something to do with how ionic or cordova builds the type="time"

~Edit2

Seems to be a localisation issue as it works correctly on ios also.

Comment: fiddle/plnkr please.
by default `<input type="time" >` is having 24H:mm format

Comment: i cant fiddle it as it was only happening when using ionic serve to test the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using angularjs expression

```css
{{booking.time | date:"h:mma"}}
```

Which will filter your data only at UI side. So change logic in your controller similar to this

```css
var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
var _time = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: this works and retruns me a string, but the <input ng-model='booking.time' type='time'> expects a date object not a string so it doesnt display still. i tried using new Date($filter('date')(new Date(),'HH:mma')); to make a date object out of a string, but when i put that new object into the html it didnt show (but didnt throw an error either, so i might be on the right track)